# table doesn't contain proper design in php mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

My code is:

```
for($i=$start_time; $i<$end_time; $i+=86400){    
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td ROWSPAN=4>';
  echo date('d/m/Y', $i);
  echo '</td>'; 
  echo '</tr>'; 

   for($j=1;$j<4;$j++){   
    while($row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($res1)) 
    {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td width=100px>'."1".'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row1['karmname'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row1['karmdesi'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row1['karmoffice'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row1['karmmobile'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
   }
}
```

But in output I want proper format first row is proper but in second row date 02/01/2015 print after data print. so in all the rows I want proper data like first row. kindly help me out to resolve this issue.
thanks in advance.

Comment: `<td ROWSPAN=4>` yet you have 5 rows..

Answer (score 0):

I can't work out from your question which way around you want your table to show, but one of these layouts should work for you:

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='5'>heading</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1</td>
        <td>Row 2</td>
        <td>Row 3</td>
        <td>Row 4</td>
        <td>Row 5</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan='5'>heading</td>
        <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>        
        <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image: HTML Table layouts]

Comment: i want 2nd table that you mentioned.but i get exact format for first row. from second row i can't get like first row,

Comment: I can't really work out what youe are trying to achieve - otherwise I could modify your code to work.  Sorry.

Comment: Ol thanks.But tell me one thing that I have one html table.

Comment: Ok thanks. But tell me one thing that I have one html table which contain some data Now I want to store data from html table in my my sql database using php.how can I get this ?